# How can I get OSX Terminal.app to open fullscreen and not cascade?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I prefer to have separate Terminal App windows rather than tabs. If I open a new windows then it always wants to cascade and I can never get it to go fullscreen.

Solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just tried this with 10.4 and it seems to work.  Open Terminal, maximize the window, go to File -> Use Settings As Defaults.

<kbd>⌘-N</kbd> creates new terminals maximized.  Quitting completely and firing it back up it comes up maximized.

Comment: Ok. I did this and it still will open a little further down from the bar... Annoying. I'll give iTerm a try.

Cheers.

Comment: Maximized works, but full screen doesn't

Comment: On recent versions of macOS (Ventura at least), the menu bar item is called Shell instead of File.

Answer (score 4):

@Sean Bright has the right answer for Terminal.app, but I'd like to mention that if you replace it with [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/), you get all kinds of good stuff that Terminal doesn't have, like Bookmarks and a full-screen, no menubar mode that's really good for scaring the hell out of non power-users who aren't expecting it. Excellent value for office jokery! ;-)

Comment: I'll give it a spin.